# Django template doesn't load anything (blank screen)

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, web

**SOLVED, I'm really sorry it was a beginner's mistake... The problem was in my _layouts/base.html, it didn't rendere because it missed the HTML in < !DOCTYPE >**

**You can view the _layout/base.html in the pastebin link**

I crawled the whole internet and still can't find what I did wrong here's my code :
**Views.py :**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import TemplateView   
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def home_page(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello')

class HomePageView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

class HomePageView2(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

**urls.py :**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from app1.views import *
#from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',HomePageView.as_view(), name = 'home.html'),
    url(r'^1/$',HomePageView2.as_view(template_name="home.html")),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^nn/$', home_page )
]
```

**home.html:**

```html
{% extends '_layouts/base.html' %}

{% block headline %}<h1>Welcome to the PyCon Survival Guide</h1>{% endblock  %}

{% block content %}
<p>Howdy {% if user.is_authenticated %} {{ user.username }}{% endif %} </p>
{% endblock %}
```

**my _layouts/base.html :**
http: //pastebin.com/LVHbduqm

Neither **HomePageView**, nor **HomePageView2** render my template !

**settings.py and my folder tree :**
[settings.py and my folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhc9s.jpg)

**P.S. :**
[Example of blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1EWw.jpg)

Comment: If you open the network tab in your browser does it gives any error code like 400 or 500?

Comment: It shows Status 200.

In CMD is like so : GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 0

Comment: Can you debug the view con pdb and manually start the manage.py runserver and check if it's hiting the api view?

Comment: umm, sorry but I'm still a beginner and don't know how to do that !

Comment: I see you solved problem.  I couldn't read pastebin link, but its best to insert code into your question using {} button, or indenting 4 characters for each line.  Why don't you show what you changed in an answer, and mark it as accepted -- future questioners will then be able to refer to your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this may seem silly to ask, but what does your home.html look like?

If you are getting back a 200, but nothing is rendering maybe your home.html is blank?

Answer (score 1):

It's a slightly different method to the one you're using but

**views.py**

```
class HomePageView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

becomes

```
def home_page_view(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

and **urls.py**

```
url(r'^$',HomePageView.as_view(), name = 'home.html'),
```

becomes

```
url(r'^$', home_page_view, name = 'home'),
```

Comment: heh... I've tried this one too before, it doen't work either and can't understand why :( ... It renders a blank screen,too ...

Comment: In your `settings.py` write `print BASE_DIR` and paste what it outputs when you run `./manage.py runserver`

Comment: D:\Virtualenv\pycon\site\src

Comment: What was the problem? It's worth writing what actually fixed it and writing it up as an answer of your own rather than marking mine as the answer if it didn't fix it. Glad it's fixed, though!